# How to load the $mdDialog Angular Material service in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-material

I am using the Angular Material library and I am unable to get the $mdDialog working. I am not sure if i am loading/injecting the service properly.

Here is the code:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {...omitted} ])
  .service('selectedStudentService', function() {...omitted} ])
  .service('appService', function($mdDialog){
      this.showAlert = function(title, message, $mdDialog) { 
        $mdDialog.show(
                 $mdDialog.alert()
                .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('#popupContainer')))
                .clickOutsideToClose(true)
                .title(title)
                .textContent(message)
                .ariaLabel()
                .ok('OK!')
                .targetEvent(messag
        );
```

The error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
```

Any thoughts on what i am doing wrong?

Note that if I use the same function under a controller in another page it works ok for me as with the following code

```
mainApp.controller('aController', function ($mdDialog) { 
     $scope.showAlert = function(title, message) {
            $mdDialog.show(
            $mdDialog.alert()
            .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('#popupContainer')))
            .clickOutsideToClose(true)
            .title('Success')
            .textContent(message)
            .ariaLabel('b')
            .ok('OK!')
            .targetEvent(message)
            );
        };
```

};

Please help

$mdDialog API Documentation URL: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but try this.  When I get home to a computer, I'll double check it.  I personally think that this should be left in a controller not a service.

You defined $mdDialog twice.  In show alert you pass it as your third argument.  I replaced that with the parent element.  The services really shouldn't get elements on the page.

```
mainApp.service('appService', function($mdDialog){ 
    return { 
        showAlert: function(title, message, parentElement) {
            $mdDialog.show(
                $mdDialog.alert()
                 .parent(parentElement)
                 .clickOutsideToClose(true)
                 .title(title)
                 .textContent(message)
                 .ariaLabel() .ok('OK!')
                 .targetEvent(message )
            );
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like Bryan said, its about the double $mdDialog. Since you put it in the function arguments, when its called its null, since you didn't pass it from the controller.

Another thing to have in mind is that you are specifying the targetEvent with your message variable.

```
 .targetEvent(message)
```

According to the examples from the material website, you should pass the event click there

```
.service('appService', function ($mdDialog) {
    this.showAlert = function (ev, title, message) {
        $mdDialog.show(
            $mdDialog.alert()
                .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('#popupContainer')))
                .clickOutsideToClose(true)
                .title(title)
                .textContent(message)
                .ariaLabel()
                .ok('OK!')
                .targetEvent(ev)
        )
    }
})
```

Your controller should look something like this:

```
.controller('someCtrl', function ($scope, appService) {
    $scope.showAlert = function (ev, title, message) {
        appService.showAlert(ev, title, message)
    }
})
```

And the html like this:

```
<button ng-click="showAlert($event, 'I'm the title', 'I'm the message')">show</button>
```

Make sure that the container is always on the page when the service is called.